# Purge emails using PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I have a PHP script that empties a mailbox every day. The problem is, that all deleted emails are moved to trash and trash is never purged.

I used PHP IMAP commands for handling the mailbox.

```
$this->_mbox = imap_open(
    $this->_data['server'],
    $this->_data['user'],
    $this->_data['pass'],
    OP_SILENT
)

...
imap_delete($this->_mbox, $index);

...
imap_expunge($this->_mbox);
```

How do I purge the trash?

**EDIT:**

imap_delete() removes the emails completely (also from trash). Now i'm just trying to find a way to read the trash folder. i tried opening the directory the same way i open the inbox without success.

Comment: try:   imap_delete($this->_mbox, "$index:$index");   But according to docs, imap_expunge should empty the trash (if called once, just before imap_close)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that the problem is in `$index`?

If you want to wipe all the Trash mailbox, try this instead :

```
<?php
$conn = @imap_open("\{$server/$serverType}Trash", $user, $pass) 
   or die("Connection to folder failed");

// delete email(s)
@imap_delete($conn,'1:*');   // to clear out an entire mailbox.
@imap_expunge($conn);
echo "Trash is empty.";
?>
```

Hope this helps! Credits goes to [jacky](http://en.php.net/manual/fr/function.imap-delete.php#37300)

Comment: tried that actually, didn't manage to connect to Trash folder

Comment: Now: {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Trash